# Accessing files from Mac OS X in VMWare Fusion?

Tags: virtualization, vmware, file-transfer

I'm running VMWare Fusion on a Boot Camp partition. When I launch the virtual machine, I see the C:\ drive which is the BOOTCAMP partition, but I don't see the other hard drive (D:) which is visible when launching boot camp directly. I realize that I can drag and drop files between OS X and the virtual machine, but I was wondering if this is the only method of accessing OS X files from the virtual machine. Is there no way to have it show the second hard drive so that every file I want to access doesn't have to be copied over?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend using the Shared Folders feature in VMware Fusion.

I have a Boot Camp partition as well running Windows 7. When I need to access files that are on the Mac OS X side from within Windows, I go the VM preferences and enable each folder I want to share (you can share multiple folders form different locations). All shared folders will then be shown on the Z:\ drive in Windows.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is very similar to what I was looking for. It's much better than having to copy every single file you want over.